# Why would any one use Firebase REST API instead of using of Firebase Libraries

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using Firebase for 'Android' for very long time without realizing that it has REST service that I can use with the help of any backend library such as the SDK-HTTPUrlConnection or any other third party library such as Retrofit or Volley. I tried using that to see why is it different? Why would I stop using the easy things Google gives to us in the Firebase to use the REST API, I actually could not answer that question, please any know why does it exist, is it not made for Android (although it works cuz it is just a normal REST)? or Why do u think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The REST API is for development environments that don't have a provided client library.  Client libraries are only provided for Android, iOS, and web.  Server libraries are only provided for Node.js, Java, Python, and Go.  What if you need to access Realtime Database from C++?  Or Perl?  Use the REST API - it's pretty much universally available.

If the Android library is working for you, then keep using it.  No need to worry about the REST API.

Comment: thank u for answer, that really helped